# Not able to redirect the URL contain %00

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect a URL which contains symbols and numbers, characters to some other URL and... URL which contains `%00` at the end needs to redirect to another URL.

Example:

`www.example.com/asdnsadnas%00` redirect to *another URL*.

`%00` is not being accepted in redirect URL, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

How you handle this really depends on what other "symbols and numbers" you are referring to and where in the URL these occur.

Since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path and `%00` is *NULL* then to catch `%00` in the URL-path you can try matching against `THE_REQUEST`, which contains the *raw* first line of the request (which is not %-decoded).

> `www.example.com/asdnsadnas%00` redirect to *another URL*.

For example, try the following near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /asdnsadnas%00\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^asdnsadnas /another-url [R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* just checks the first part of the URL, up to the `%00`.

If you just wanted to redirect `/asdnsadnas` and simply ignore everything that follows that URL-path then you don't need to explicitly check for `%00`, so you can remove the `RewriteCond` directive.

---

> `www.example.com.nz/XYZABC%00` needs to redirects to `www.example.com.nz/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/ XYZABC` - any letter or symbols etc but I need any URL at the end `%00` need to redirect to another URL.

(I assume that *space* in the target URL is just typo?)

In this case you don't necessarily need to match `%00` (a "character" that you don't want). Just be specific about the characters you do want to match (which is likely to be a smaller subset).

For example, the following would redirect `/XYZABC` to `/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/XYZABC`. The trailing `%00` is ignored.

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+) /insurance-hub-page/xsserror/$1 [R,L]
```

> ...but I need any URL at the end `%00` need to redirect to another URL.

Not sure what you mean by that?

> if URL contains any special charcters or symbols etc need to redirects to another url Example: `www.example.com/%28dsajkd%20nkasd%20daskdasj%00`

You could just check to see if the requested URL contains any %-encoded characters, which seems to fit your example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} %
RewriteRule ^ /another-url [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi,

www.example.com.nz/XYZABC%00 needs to redirects to

www.example.com.nz/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/

XYZABC - any letter or symbols etc but I need any URL at the end%00 need to redirect to another URL.

I hope you understand now.. thanks

Comment: Is that any rule if URL contains any special charcters or symbols etc need to redirects to another url

Example www.example.com/%28dsajkd%20nkasd%20daskdasj%00

Comment: No, I need to redirect if any one try spoofing in url , like adding symbols special characters in the url, needs to redirect to anothers url

Comment: I've updated my answer. (Note there was a typo in my initial answer - the first `RewriteRule` should have been `RewriteCond` - now corrected.)

Comment: Current code which I have
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 301 ^example1.example2.co.nz//(.*)$ https://www.example1.example2.co.nz/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/$1
</IfModule>

Comment: If any body type in the URL www.exam1.exam.co.nz/%2fass%20dsaa%20sadd%20dsad - it will redirect to https://www.exam1.exam2.co.nz/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/ perfectly but if they tried same URL at end%00 looks like  www.example1.example2.co.nz/%2fasdas%20dsadsa%20sadasd%20dsad%00 , it wont works.. it just a example they may be tried any charcters , I need if any one type www.exam1.exam2.co.nz/%2fass%20dsaa%20sadd%20dsad%00 needs to redirect to https://www.exam1.exam2.co.nz/insurance-hub-page/xsserror/

Comment: Hi, Is that possible if URL contain any symbols or special charcters needs to redirect to another url, example, www.example.com/%dasda%20sdad%23qwedsa%2qads - > www.example.com/test